# Delay option for jQuery Ui Sortable doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I am using jQuery UI Touch Punch to enable the Sortable function on iOS Safari.  Sortable on iOS works fine, but I am unable to see any of the options (i.e. delay, distance, etc.) function properly.  All of the options work in browsers, just not on iOS.  I've listed the loaded dependencies and the order I use.  Again, the problem is not with Sortable on iOS, rather the Sortable options.  Any suggestions?

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>         
<script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script>$( function() {
            $( "#sortable" ).sortable({ scroll:"true", helper:"clone",     opacity: 0.5, cancel: false, delay: 500, distance:10});
        });</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you have the wrong version of punch ui or misplaced it. Here is a working example.

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>      
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<style>#sortable li { padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 20px; }</style>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<script>
$( function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable({ scroll:"true", helper:"clone", opacity: 0.5, cancel: false, delay: 500, distance:10});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I used your simple example and it works.  I compared the .js files and they are the same.  So my original html has a problem that is interfering.  I'll get back once I figure out the culprit.  Thanks.

Comment: My problem was that I had a malformed input tag as part of a list-group item.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Scott Glad that it helped. Could you please set it as the correct answer?

Comment: Will do.  Now needlessly typing more characters so my comment is accepted.